# How to force execution of a different thread

Tags: python

I have one main thread that does some rather CPU intensive operation. The thread has to hold a lock for all its calculations.

Then there are some other threads which occasionally require the same lock for brief amounts of time.

How can I force the main the main thread to occasionally allow the other threads to execute without slowing it down if there are no other threads?

A periodic

```
lock.release()
time.sleep(x)
lock.acquire()
```

for some x would pass control to another thread, but slow the main thread down if there are no other threads.

On the other hand, without the `sleep()` call  the GIL seems to interfere here. Since the main thread has the GIL when it executes `release()`, the other thread is apparently not able to return from `acquire()` immediately. Therefore, the main thread continues with its own `acquire()` method and the other threads never get the lock unless a GIL switch happens to coincide exactly with me releasing my own lock.

What's the proper solution for this problem? Is there a way to force a GIL release? Basically I want some magic piece of code that makes sure that in the following test script the second thread always gets the lock first:

```
import threading
import time

class t1 (threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
    print "Second thread waiting for lock"
    lock.acquire()
    print "Second thread got lock"
    lock.release()

lock = threading.Lock()
lock.acquire()

t = t1()
t.start()
time.sleep(1)

lock.release()
time.sleep(0) # this works very often, but not all the time
lock.acquire()
print "Main thread got lock"
lock.release()
```

Comment: you might use a Queue.PriorityQueue() to feed a worker thread doing everything that need to acquire the lock. This way you'll be sure that small task with high priority would be done right after a chunk of your intensive CPU operation is finished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Merely releasing the GIL doesn't guarantee that other threads will have a chance to run.

In Unix, the call you really want is `sched_yield()`.  There's no interface to that function in the Python standard library; it would be straightforward to add one with a native module.

`usleep(0)` and `select()` are sometimes used for the same purpose, though it's not always the same depending on the system scheduler.  Windows, you want Sleep(0).  Use time.sleep(0) for both of those.

Comment: time.sleep(0) does not work. Try the script that I just attached to the question. Most of the time the second thread gets the lock first, but sometimes it's the main thread.

Comment: Whether to schedule another thread during the sleep is up to the scheduler.  There'll no *guarantee* of what the scheduler will do; it's valid for it to decide that the main thread should continue.  A good scheduler should be *fair*--that is, this *should* work often enough that no thread will get completely starved, but it's risky to depend heavily on scheduler fairness.  In general, having two threads that constantly compete over a single mutex which they have to fight over to execute at all is poor threading design.

Comment: Special thanks to this buggy site, which, when I try to work around its broken formatting in the above comment, first says that I can only edit a comment every 5 seconds (pointless), then says "this comment can no longer be edited".  Welcome to PainInTheAssArbitraryRestrictionOverflow.

Comment: unfortunately sched_yield actually gives worse results than time.sleep(0). I tried the above test script with sched_yield() provided by [llfuse](http://code.google.com/p/python-llfuse/), and generally the main thread keeps running.

Answer (score 0):

Calling [`select.select()`](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html#select.select) with a timeout of 0 will release the GIL for a brief moment.

Comment: Good idea, but it's not working. Try to insert it in the sample script that I just posted.

Comment: That's because the threading library hasn't decided that the other thread should run. If you want to improve the chances that some other thread will get selected to run then you need a non-zero timeout.